# Not able to load a new page because of error

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I have created a page and set return view correctly. However, It shows 404 error. 
Since, I'm new to Laravel, I couldn't able to find the solution.

Below are my codes:

```
Routing:
<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('website.pages.home');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');


/********** admin routes start *************/

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/','Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::get('/dashboard','Admin\DashboardController@index');
    Route::get('/assignrole','Admin\AssignRoleController@index');
    Route::post('/assignrole','Admin\AssignRoleController@assignrole');
    Route::get('/assignrole/{id}/{role}','Admin\AssignRoleController@showuser');
    Route::resource('/user','Admin\UserController');

});

/********** admin routes end *************/





  Controller:
        <?php
        namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
        use Illuminate\Http\Request;
        use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
        use App\Role;
        class ImageController extends Controller
        {

            public function index()
            {
                return view('admin.pages.dashboard');
            }

            public function create()
            {
                $roles = Role::all();
              return view('admin.pages.image',['roles'=>$roles]);
            }

            public function store(Request $request)
            {
                  return redirect('/admin/imageupload');
            }


        }
```

My File Path is:resources\views\admin\pages\image

And in my Database the sidebar is fetching from The photo is attached above.

https://ibb.co/1qJ7B4Z

Any help will be apprenticed.

Comment: for which url,u got 404 error?

Comment: public/admin/imageupload

Comment: where you have define this route

Comment: Why adding  `public` ? && there is no route....

Comment: @AJITHLALR did u defined this admin/imageupload in routes?

Comment: no you have to create route for it and also its view

Comment: @KumarPraveen Thanks as per your suggestion i added routing and its work fine. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: @Rp9 Thanks for the help as per your suggestion I got my Solution.